# How to set request time for several hours - IIS and ASP: NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, timeout

I have WebAPI writteni in ASP.NET 4.6.2. 
One endpoint has a duration of more than 1 hour. I need to set up IIS and application pool for 4 hours.
Execution of endpoint always ends in 1 hour.

```xml
<!-- timeout to 4 hours -->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" executionTimeout="14400" />
```

Stack:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'MyDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Database()
   at Fullsys.MyIS.Core.BL.Common.AppUnitOfWork.RollbackTransaction()
   at Fullsys.MyIS.Modules.Planovani.Business.MrpPlanBusiness.Rollback() in S:\Projects\net\MyIS\MyApp\Verze-1\Modules\Planovani\Business\MrpPlanBusiness.cs:line 269
   at Fullsys.MyIS.Modules.Planovani.PlanovaniFacade.FinishAkceSChybou(AkceEnum akce) in S:\Projects\net\MyIS\MyApp\Verze-1\Modules\Planovani\PlanovaniFacade.cs:line 877
   at Fullsys.MyIS.Modules.Planovani.PlanovaniFacade.ExecProtokolAkce(Action validate, Action action, AkceEnum akce, Int64 id) in S:\Projects\net\MyIS\MyApp\Verze-1\Modules\Planovani\PlanovaniFacade.cs:line 865
   at Fullsys.MyIS.Modules.Planovani.PlanovaniFacade.CreateVyrobniZakazky(Int64 id, ProtocolInfo& protocolInfo) in S:\Projects\net\MyIS\MyApp\Verze-1\Modules\Planovani\PlanovaniFacade.cs:line 587
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Comment: This error is not an IIS timeout.   You should look at the timeouts on your data access library and on the datasource itself.

Comment: usually, if you have a process that long. you should separate request/start process, and check call to get results as a separate call.

Comment: I use Oracle dotConnect and ConnectionString with Connection Timeout set to 120 seconds. Other setting is default. https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html